# USA citizen wanting to cross the India-Pakistan border

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, us-citizens, pakistan

I am an American wanting to plan a trip from India into Pakistan but I have heard from other travellers that you will be rejected at the Pakistan border if you have a stamp in your passport from India.

Has anyone else had/heard of this problem and if so is there a way around it?

Comment: Unless you're trying to travel through Kashmir, (don't even think about it) that sounds just this side of absurd.

Answer (score 8):

There are no such restrictions.  If you have a valid visa for Pakistan (and you would need one), you can enter Pakistan.

Your only choice of transit is the [Wagah border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagah) which is near the city of Lahore (the provincial capital of the state of Punjab, Pakistan). On the Indian side, you would start at Delhi.

There is a bus service you can take.  The journey takes approximately 8 hours.

Of course, you can always fly as well.

Comment: [Currently](http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/delhi-lahore-bus-service-restricted-to-wagah-border-after-terror-attack-warnings-723803), due to terrorism risk, the bus drops everyone off at the border, and you walk across yourself. You then board another bus for the remainder of the journey.